# How to start docker container with dynamic url

Tags: node.js, git, docker, jenkins

My requirement is as follows:

1. Developer creates a branch in Jenkins. Lets say branch name is "mystory-101"
2. Now developer push the code to this branch
3. Jenkins job starts as soon as commit is pushed to the branch "mystory-101" and create a new docker image for this branch if not created already
4. My application is Node.js based app, so docker container starts with node.js and deployes the code from the branch "mystory-101"
5. After the code is deployed and node.js is running, then I would also like this node.js app to be accessible via the URL : https://mystory-101.mycompany.com

For this purpose I was reading this https://medium.com/swlh/ci-cd-pipeline-using-jenkins-dynamic-nodes-86ea854ff7a7
but I am not sure how to achive step #5. Can you please advice how to achive this autometically?

Comment: Medium is asking me to upgrade, after telling me access to the story once logged with my google account, .... could you clarify? If you refer to the step 5 in your own plan, that's the point you would use a plugin like "oc", or kubernetes (like in step 4), creating your Deployment, Service and Ingress. Do you have some kind of cloud (kubernetes, openshift, ...), where are you deploying this?

Comment: @SYN, thanks, could you please give me details how "OC" tool help here? I am planning to to do in kubernetes. Regarding to access to medium site, maybe if you open in incognito mode then it may work.

Comment: I meant the oc plugin (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/openshift-pipeline/), that interfaces with OpenShift, not certain it would work with a vanilla Kubernetes, though OpenShift is based on Kubernetes. Might do, otherwise go with the kubernetes plugin (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/). Your job would use those plugins creating Kubernetes objects (eg: https://github.com/Worteks/docker-ldap/blob/master/openshift/ci.yaml)

Comment: Actually, if you don't want to use a plugin, you could also make sure the kubectl client is installed on your Jenkins agent, inject a kubeconfig accessing your cluster, and just apply yamls in your pipeline, as you would do from your workstation.

Comment: @SYN, many thanks again for your help, unfortunately I did not find the steps how to tell Kubernetes to expose the node js app on user defined URL, such as "https://mystory-101.mycompany.com". Could you please point me that steps?

Comment: Once you have your Deployment running: if you do not have a Service yet, create one. Its selectors should match the labels in your deployment (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service), then create an Ingress object, which may define a `spec.rules[].host`, that you can set from your Pipeline (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls). Depending on your ingress controller, there may be additional annotations, labels, ... to pass, maybe a Secret with your TLS cert, maybe your ingress controller already does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformatting answers from commentaries, having a Jenkins installation and Kubernetes cluster, you may automate your deployments using a Jenkins plugin such as [`oc`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/openshift-pipeline/) or [`kubernetes`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/), or you could prefer using the `kubectl` client directly, assuming your agents do have that binary.

Not going through the RBAC specifics, you would probably need a ServiceAccount for Jenkins, and use a token (can be found in a Secret named after your ServiceAccount). That ServiceAccount should have enough privileges to create resources in the namespaces you intend to deploy stuff into -- usually the `edit` ClusterRole, with a namespace-scoped RoleBinding:

```
kubectl create sa jenkins -n my-namespace
kubectl create rolebinding jenkins-edit \
  --clusterrole=edit \
  --serviceaccount=my-namespace:jenkins-edit \
  --namespace=my-namespace
```

Once Jenkins is done building your image, you would deploy it to Kubernetes, most likely creating a Deployment, a Service, and an Ingress, substituting resource names, namespaces and your ingress requested FQDN to match your requirements.

Prepare your deployment yaml, something like:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-BRANCH
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: app-BRANCH
  template:
     spec:
       containers:
       - image: my-registry/path/to/image:BRANCH
[...]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-BRANCH
spec:
  selector:
    name: app-BRANCH
  ports:
[...]
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-BRANCH
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app-BRANCH.my-base-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-BRANCH
```

Then, have your Jenkins agent apply that configuration, substituting values properly:

```
sed "s|BRANCH|$BRANCH|" deploy.yaml | kubectl apply -n my-namespace -f-
kubectl wait -n my-namespace deploy/app-$BRANCH --for=condition=Available
kubectl logs -n my-namespace deploy/app-$BRANCH --tail=200
```